Floating 6x12 feet laundry room on concrete slab is separating/sinking from the rest of the 1700-ish sqft pier and beam house (brick exterior)
The laundry room in my house is not attached to the rest of the house. However, the laundry room's roof seems connected to the rest of the house's roof.
The laundry room is on a concrete slab while the rest of the house is pier and beam.
On the line where the laundry room's brick meets the brick from the rest of the house, there seems to be a thick bead of silicone. It may be working as some sort of expansion joint.
That bead of silicone is starting to develop holes. This is making me think that the laundry room is sinking. I have not dug around the laundry room to know what the foundation looks like but it's definitely on a concrete slab.
Any experience in handling this situation? Is there a car or house jack that I can rent to lift the laundry room's concrete slab and some how put a post underneath or something?
Here is a 3D model of the house and the laundry room:






It looks like someone converted a patio into a room. The patio doesn't need a footing, a room does.
